# NGRX/store sideEffect issue with startWith

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a side-effect that looks like this:

```ts
@Effect()
loadAll$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(reservationsActions.LOAD_ALL)
  .startWith(new reservationsActions.LoadAll())
  .switchMap(() =>
    this.reservationsService.index() 
   .map((reservations: Reservation[]) => new reservationsActions.LoadAllSuccess(reservations))
);
```

I grabbed that from this repo [ngrx example](https://github.com/avatsaev/angular-contacts-app-example)

and I get the following error:

> Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Actions'.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this effect exactly? Even if you were to return `new reservationsActions.LoadAll()` your not using that result in your `switchMap`. If you could indicate the intent of your code.

Comment: I believe this loads all the 'reservations' initially. I using this code from the example. 

this is dispatched in the component ngOnInint

    this.store.dispatch(new reservationsActions.LoadAll());
then this side eefect loads all the reservations from the service and then dispatches reservationsActions.LoadAllSuccess(reservations)).

I'm just confused by the 'startWith' does not exist error.

Comment: what example are you referring to? the link above does not contain this example (or any effects?) However I would make sure you're using ngrx 4.0 as well.

Answer (score 3):

When upgrading to rxjs 6 you need to adjust your syntax to use the pipe operator.

**Original**

```
  @Effect()
  loadAll$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
   .ofType(reservationsActions.LOAD_ALL)
   .startWith(new reservationsActions.LoadAll())
   .switchMap(() =>
     this.reservationsService.index() 
    .map((reservations: Reservation[]) => new 
         reservationsActions.LoadAllSuccess(reservations))
   );
```

**New**

```
  @Effect()
  loadAll$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(reservationsActions.LOAD_ALL),
   startWith(new reservationsActions.LoadAll()),
  switchMap(() =>
    this.reservationsService.index() 
   .map((reservations: Reservation[]) => new 
reservationsActions.LoadAllSuccess(reservations))
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

just figured it out,
this was missing.

import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith'